${\mathrm{Ext}}_{k[\epsilon]}^1(k, k)$ and ${\mathrm{Ext}}_{k[X]}^1(k, k)$.
For a field $k$, I am calculating ${\mathrm{Ext}}_{k[\epsilon]}^1(k, k)$ and ${\mathrm{Ext}}_{k[X]}^1(k, k)$, where $\epsilon^2 = 0$. However, there seems no complete explanation as far as I checked. I tried to do this by using bar-construction (bar-resolution?) or Koszul complex, about which I am quite unfamiliar. I want to know how one calculates these groups.

for the k[x] case, it should depend on how you consider k as a k[x] module right? ie k=k[x]/(x-a) and it depends on what value of a you choose for your left and right field? Geometrically, this would correspond to picking two different points on the affine line. Once you have this presentation, you should be able to make a 3 term projective resolution k[x]->k[x]->k (where the last map is the quotient) and compute exts from there? I assume it'd be similar for k[epsilon].

For $k[\epsilon]$, have you actually tried to use the bar complex? That is one example where it is actually very accessible.

As mentioned by Toyesh, rather than using the bar or Koszul complex, here it's easier to compute a convenient resolution by hand. That is, we need a sequence of free modules and maps such that $\cdots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to k \to 0$ is an exact sequence.
First, we need a free module which maps surjectively into $k$: the easiest way is to take $P_0 = k[X]$ and $\delta_0 \colon k[X] \to k$ sends $k$ to itself and $X$ to $0$. Then $\ker \delta_0$ is the $k[X]$-module generated by $X$: we can map surjectively into this kernel by setting $P_1 = k[X]$ and $\delta_1 \colon k[X] \to k[X]$ given by $p \mapsto pX$. Then $\delta_1$ is an injective map, so we are done and $0 \to k[X] \to k[X] \to k \to 0$ is a free resolution of $k$.
To compute $\mathrm{Ext}$, note that $\mathrm{Hom}_{k[X]}(k[X],k) \cong k$,
so taking $\mathrm{Hom}_{k[X]}(\cdot,k)$ on the resolution gives us a chain $0 \to k \to k \to 0$, where one can check the induced boundary map in the middle is $0$. Therefore $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{k[X]}(k,k) \cong k$ for $i=0,1$ and is trivial otherwise.
For $k[\epsilon]$, we can proceed the same way, except that we will get an infinite resulution $\cdots \to k[\epsilon] \to k[\epsilon] \to k[\epsilon] \to k \to 0$ (think: what are the $k[\epsilon]$-linear maps that make the sequence exact?). Then you can apply $\mathrm{Hom}_{k[\epsilon]}(\cdot, k)$ and take homology of the chain you get, which will give you $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{k[\epsilon]}(k,k) \cong k$
